# Vertical Owl Carousel

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I am working with owl carousel and would like to make a vertical image slider. On adding items,  I need to place it below the previous image and the items need to slide vertically. Any help?
Here's my code like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 todayspecialcolumn">
            <h1>Today's Special</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-10  todayspecial owl-carousel owl-theme">        
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="card todayspecialfood">
                            <div class="todaysimg">
                                <img src="{{url('public/images/fooditems/img4.jpg')}}" alt="foodimage.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row foodprice">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h5>Food name</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h5>Rs 500</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="card todayspecialfood">
                            <div class="todaysimg">
                                <img src="{{url('public/images/fooditems/img4.jpg')}}" alt="foodimage.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row foodprice">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h5>Food name</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h5>Rs 500</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="card todayspecialfood">
                            <div class="todaysimg">
                                <img src="{{url('public/images/fooditems/img4.jpg')}}" alt="foodimage.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row foodprice">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h5>Food name</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h5>Rs 500</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="items">
                        <div class="card todayspecialfood">
                            <div class="todaysimg">
                                <img src="{{url('public/images/fooditems/img4.jpg')}}" alt="foodimage.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row foodprice">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <h5>Food name</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h5>Rs 500</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>                  
        </div>
```

and js code is like this:

```
$('.todayspecial').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    dots:false,
    autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:1000,
    animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
    animateIn: 'slideInUp',

    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
})
```

this code displays single image that slides next image vertically, but I want to place 3 image items vertically and then slide vertically.

Comment: Please add your sample code, what you already tried and what failed.

Comment: sample code added, Sir